# Refresh JFrame from JDialog button and refresh table

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I started developing an application that works with tables. Initially, JFrame's table is empty. When I click on add a row button on JFrame JDialog window opens. In it, I write attributes required and when I click on save, they are supposed to be saved in a list represented by a table on JFrame and shown when I close JDialog. This is the part that won't work. I know I did model good and everything else as much as I can see because when I click on a button I added after that that implements a method for JFrame refresh it works. Please help me.

**method in JFrame class:**

```
public void fillTable() {


    ModelTabele mt = new ModelTabele(true, kontrolor.Kontrolor.vratiObjekatKontrolora().vratiAsistente());
    jTable1.setModel(mt);


} //applying model on Jframe
```

**and a method in JDialog class:**

```
private void jbtSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    Asistent a = new Asistent();
    a.setSifra(Integer.valueOf(jtfSifra.getText()));
    a.setIme(jtfIme.getText());
    a.setPrezime(jtfPrezime.getText());
    a.setTitula(jtfTitula.getText());
    a.setPredmet((Predmet) jcbPredmeti.getSelectedItem());
    kontrolor.Kontrolor.vratiObjekatKontrolora().dodajAsistenta(a);

    this.dispose();


} //after adding attributes, JDialog needs to be closed and object is saved in a list represented in table
```

Comment: First of all, your variables and methods aren't in english. And since you don't tell us what is what, we can't even begin to try and encrypt it. Second what the heck does this mean: _"object is saved in a list represented in table"_. Do you have a JTable. If so, please mention that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need to do.

- Pass in the `TableModel` to the dialog class.
- For that you will need to change the constructor of the dialog
- Then just update the model from the dialog class.
- Something like: <sub>(Note: since you aren't using English and I have no idea what your variables and methods are, I will use my own)</sub>:

  ```
  class MyDialog extends JDialog {
      DefaultTableModel model;

      public MyDialog(JFrame frame, modal true, DefaultTableModel model) {
          super(frame, modal);
          this.model = model;
      }

      private void saveButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          ...
          model.addRow(...)
      }
  }

  class MyFrame extends JFrame {
      private JTable jTable1;

      private void showDialogActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
          MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(this, true, model);
      }
  }
  ```

Now the same `TableModel` is referenced in both classes, and can be updated from either.

Comment: Better idea, build the dialog with getters (and possibly setters) and when it returns, apply the changes to what ever...you could even yes a JOptionPane instead of a JDialog

Comment: @MadProgrammer Curious, why do you say that's a better idea?

Comment: Cause you're not then exposing the table model to unwanted modifications. The responsibility of the dialog is to collect information and pass it back to the caller - IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Step back and take a look at the errors of responsibility.  The dialog is responsible for collecting information and notifying the calling what options the user selected (save, cancel, what ever), the dialog shouldn't be modifying the state of the program (IMHO).

To this end, instead of creating a custom `JDialog`, you could consider making the dialog into a `JPanel` (without the buttons) and use a `JOptionPane` instead...

```
// editorPane is your panel that gathers the information
int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, editorPane, 
                "Add",
                JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 
                null,
                new Object[]{"Save", "Cancel"},
                "Save"
);
if (option == 0) {
    // Get the details from the editor pane...
    // Update model
}
```

Basically, you would display the editor pane to the user, via a `JOptionPane`.  When the user selects one of the available options, in this example `save` or `cancel`, you would check what the user has selected and based on that result, either get the values from the `editorPane` and then apply them to the table model or simply ignore the changes...as an example

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this one:

1. brute force: as @peeskillet suggest, you can pass your coveted `TableModel` around and let anyone update it.  That should get your code working, but it really doesn't feel right.
2. keep all your updating code in your `JFrame` class, and launch a modal `JOptionPane` which blocks processing as @MadProgrammer suggests.
3. abstract your `JFrame` class's model-updating methods by having it implement an interface (of your design), and pass your `JFrame` class as an instance of this interface to your `JDialog` class.  In your `save` method, you call your interface API with the data as input.